# mostrar autocompletado de atributos de html en vscode

Tags: django, vscode, autocompletar

estoy entrando en esto de la programación backend.

tengo un problema con el ide vscode y el auto completado:

al intentar poner los atributos de los marcadores en el modo de lenguaje "django-html", no me aparece el auto completado de los mismos:

lenguaje mode :"django- html"
[image: autocompletado de django-html]

lenguaje mode:"html"
[image: autocompletado de html]

intente agregando la extencion HTML CSS Support

y la configuracion :

```
"html-css-class-completion.HTMLLanguages": [
    "html",
    "vue",
    "razor",
    "blade",
    "handlebars",
    "twig",
    "django-html",
    "php",
    "markdown",
    "erb",
    "ejs",
    "svelte"
]
```

pero sigue sin funcionar.

Answer (score 2):

Necesitas activar la extensión emmet. Añade esta línea a .vscode/settings.json:

```
"emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "django-html": "html"
},
```

Espero te sea útil.